# Автовход после регистрации php

Tags: php

Автовход не работает
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина?

```
<?php 
        require 'db.php';

$data = $_POST;




if ( isset($data['do_signup']) )
{

    $errors = array();
    if ( trim($data['login']) == '' )
    {
        $errors[] = 'В  ведите логин';
    }

    if ( trim($data['email']) == '' )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Введите Email';
    }

    if ( $data['password'] == '' )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Введите пароль';
    }

    if ( $data['password_2'] != $data['password'] )
    {
        $errors[] = 'Повторный пароль введен не верно!';
    }

    
    if ( R::count('users', "login = ?", array($data['login'])) > 0)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким логином уже существует!';
    }


    if ( R::count('users', "email = ?", array($data['email'])) > 0)
    {
        $errors[] = 'Пользователь с таким Email уже существует!';
    }

$sex=($data['sex']);

        if ( empty($errors) )
        {
            
            $user = R::dispense('users');
            $user->login = $data['login'];
            $user->email = $data['email'];
      $user->sex = $data['sex'];
      $user->status = 1;
    
            $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //пароль нельзя хранить в открытом виде, мы его шифруем при помощи функции password_hash для php > 5.6
      
            R::store($user);
      $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
      header('Location: index.php');
            echo '<div style="color:green;">  Вы зарегистрированы    </div><hr>';
        }else
        {
            echo '<div id="errors" style="color:red;">' .array_shift($errors). '</div><hr>';
        }

    }

  
?>

<form action="/signup.php" method="POST">
    <strong>Ваш логин</strong>
    <input type="text" size="15" name="login" value="<?php echo @$data['login']; ?>"><br/>

    <strong>Ваш Email</strong>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo @$data['email']; ?>"><br/>

    <strong>Ваш пароль</strong>
    <input type="password" size="15" name="password" value="<?php echo @$data['password']; ?>"><br/>

    <strong>Повторите пароль</strong>
    <input type="password" size="15" name="password_2" value="<?php echo @$data['password_2']; ?>"><br/>
  <strong> Пол:</strong>
<select name="sex"><option value="m">Мужской</option><option value="w">Женский</option></select><br/>


    <button type="submit" name="do_signup">Регистрация</button>
</form>
```

Comment: для решения даного вопроса нужно больше информации, необходимо видеть что у вас в `<form>` и полностью та часть кода php которая отвечает за обработку формы - поймите что то где на ваш взгляд имеет место проблема - не всегда верно иногда бывает что ошибка находится вовсе не там где ее ожидаешь, пожалуйста отредактируйте ваш вопрос

Comment: Помогли отредактировать

Comment: типа пользователь зарегался,  а после успешной регистрции, идет редиретк в index.php  и пользователь должен быть по-умолчанию авторизован?

Comment: а где вы проверяете что пользователь авторизирован? где идет проверка `$_SESSION['auth']`

Comment: Получается после регистрации пользователь должен сразу войти, чтобы в ручную не вводить логин, пароль

Comment: А каким образом у вас сессия инициализируется и стартует?

Comment: Честно говоря не видя что у вас в `R` статическом классе и `db.php` - тяжело понять в чем проблема, в том коде что вы скинули я не вижу реализации функций отвечающих за регистрацию. Просто исходя из названия `db.php` отвечает как я понял за регистрацию, проблема в коде почти всегда ищется методом исключения. как я писал выше без полной картины не могу сказать вам в чем ошибка